# cut from column X until the end of a tab delimited file

Tags: linux, unix, cut

If I have a file with an unknown number of column but I know I want columns X til the end, is there an easy way to use cut for this?

Let us say X=5,

I used,
`cut -f5- filename`
but it did not work.

Then I am trying to specify the -d'\t' and also it does not work.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're very close, but you're missing the dollar sign in there:

```
cut -d $'\t' -f5- file.txt
```

Comment: Oh didn't know about the minus after the 5 `-f5-` that tells to return the remainder of the string from the 5th column. +1

Comment: @Dnaiel: If you are happy with this answer, you should consider accepting it. To do so, you can click the tick to the left of this answer. Cheers.

Comment: @steve, it does not allow me to accept it right after, then I forgot bt it hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it with cut but what I'd do if I had to print the fields from X to the end would be to use awk. Assume X = 2:

```
awk '{print $(NF - 2), $(NF - 1), $NF}' <<< "1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

which results in:

```
4 5 6
```

`NF` is an awk reserved keyword that is a count of the number of fields.